# Silverlight 5 earth spinning animation with gradients is consuming a lot of CPU resources

Tags: silverlight, animation, cpu-usage, radial-gradients

I have created an endless "earth spinning" animation in silverlight, which animates two pictures. If I only use the two pictures to animate, the animation uses 2-5% of CPU. That seems ok to me and normal. If I add some simple overlay effects (Arcs with Gradients in it), the CPU usage goes up to 25%-30%, which is to much.

Here's the code. I have added comments, where the "bad code" starts and ends.

**My question is:** How could I optimize this animation? Why are overlayed gradients so CPU so demanding?

```
<UserControl
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:ed="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/drawing"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    x:Class="SpinningGlobe.MainControl"
    d:DesignWidth="640" d:DesignHeight="480" Height="450" Width="450">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Name="Vordergrund_Story"  RepeatBehavior="Forever">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" Storyboard.TargetName="Vordergrund">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:01:59" Value="877"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" Storyboard.TargetName="Hintergrund">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:01:59" Value="-877"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <!-- 1754 -->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent" Height="450" Width="450">
        <!-- Dunkle Weltkarte nach links-->
        <Canvas x:Name="Hintergrund" Margin="-507,10,-370,10" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" d:IsLocked="True">
            <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform/>
            </Canvas.RenderTransform>
            <Image Margin="0,10,0,10" Source="WELT_DUNKEL.png" Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <Image Margin="877,10,0,10" Source="WELT_DUNKEL.png" Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        </Canvas>
        <!-- Helle Weltkarte nach rechts-->
        <Canvas x:Name="Vordergrund" Margin="-1247,10,0,10" d:IsLocked="True">
            <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform/>
            </Canvas.RenderTransform>
            <Image Margin="0,10,0,10" Source="WELT_HELL.png" Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <Image Margin="877,10,0,10" Source="WELT_HELL.png" Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        </Canvas>


        <!-- HERE STARTS THE HEAVY CPU USAGE-->


        <!-- Äusserer, weisser "Wolkenring"-->
        <ed:Arc ArcThickness="225" ArcThicknessUnit="Pixel" EndAngle="360" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="450" Margin="0,0,0,0" Stretch="None" Stroke="Transparent" StartAngle="0" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="450">
            <ed:Arc.Fill>
                <RadialGradientBrush>
                    <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="0.935"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#5BFFFFFF" Offset="1"/>
                </RadialGradientBrush>
            </ed:Arc.Fill>
        </ed:Arc>
        <!-- Äusserer, weisser "Wolkenring", aber nur 1 Pixel breit, so das nach aussen eine schärfere Abgrenzung stattfindet-->
        <ed:Arc ArcThickness="1" ArcThicknessUnit="Pixel" EndAngle="360" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="450" Margin="0,0,0,0" Stretch="None" Stroke="Transparent" StartAngle="0" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="450" d:IsLocked="True">
            <ed:Arc.Fill>
                <RadialGradientBrush>
                    <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="0.935"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#5BFFFFFF" Offset="1"/>
                </RadialGradientBrush>
            </ed:Arc.Fill>
        </ed:Arc>

        <ed:Arc ArcThickness="300" ArcThicknessUnit="Pixel" EndAngle="360" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="900" Margin="-450,-230,0,-220" Stretch="None" Stroke="Transparent" StartAngle="0" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="900" Opacity="0.82" d:IsLocked="True">
            <ed:Arc.Fill>
                <RadialGradientBrush>
                    <GradientStop Color="#00000000" Offset="0.625"/>
                    <GradientStop Offset="0.884" Color="Black"/>
                </RadialGradientBrush>
            </ed:Arc.Fill>
        </ed:Arc>
        <ed:Arc ArcThickness="300" ArcThicknessUnit="Pixel" EndAngle="360" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="900" Margin="-120,-230,-330,-220" Stretch="None" Stroke="Transparent" StartAngle="0" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="900" Opacity="0.82" d:IsLocked="True">
            <ed:Arc.Fill>
                <RadialGradientBrush>
                    <GradientStop Color="#00FFFFFF" Offset="0.6"/>
                    <GradientStop Offset="0.884" Color="#A3FFFFFF"/>
                </RadialGradientBrush>
            </ed:Arc.Fill>
        </ed:Arc>


        <!-- HERE ENDS THE HEAVY CPU USAGE-->

        <!-- Maskierung in Form einer Elipse (Aufheben, um alles zu sehen!)-->
        <Grid.Clip>
            <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="225" RadiusY="225" Center="225,225"/>
        </Grid.Clip>

    </Grid>

</UserControl>
```

[image: Image of CPU heavy animation]

Answer (score 1):

I just want to leave some words, what my solution to the problem is and what I think. First of all, I could not identify any errors or obvious mistakes in the XAML.

I dont' know why, but any "arc", filled with a gradient in an animation increases the CPU load heavily. So I wouldn't recommend that. My personal thinking is, that silverlight is just not made for long or longer animations. It's all about short UI magic.

My solution is, I rendered every framework element in the animation to a PNG and used it as a picture, that I lay over the animation. For example, the black shadow on the right side was a silverlight arc with a gradient, is now a plain PNG. Looks the same. Needs no CPU.

I really love silverlight, but this behaviour disappoints me some how.